# Tkinter prevent manual input into Combobox

Tags: tkinter, combobox

I have a Tkinter Combobox with two possible values: "50" and "60"

```
frequency_var = StringVar(value="50")
freq_combobox = Combobox(root, textvariable=frequency_var, values=["50", "60"])
```

[image]

The Combobox correctly shows this two options in the dropdown menu, However the textfield is editable and the user can manually write junk on it

[image]

Usually if I want to protect a field from being writen I disable it, but then it disables the whole Combobox and I cannot select the options from the dropdown.

```
freq_combobox.config(state='disabled')
```

[image]

Is there a way to prevent users from writing to the Combobox value and only allow them to select from the options?

Is setting the state to disabled the correct way of protecting fields against being written? Or is there another better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `state="readonly"`,user could not modify the text.